Inner product spaces - Convergent
I have a question. I still worry about this definition.
Let E is an inner product space $(E,\left \langle \cdot , \cdot \right \rangle)$. A sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}=\left\{1,2,3,...\right\}}$ converges in $E$ $\Leftrightarrow \exists x\in E :\left\|x_n-x\right\|_{E}\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$.
S.t: $\forall x\in E,\left\|x\right\|_{E}= \left \langle x , x \right \rangle^{1/2}$
I am self-learning about inner product space, but in my curriculum does not tell about this definition. Does my def. true or not?
Thanks everyone for helping me so much!.

What is your question?

@Mark I want to confirm: does my statement is true?. I am confuse about this.

@TrầnNguyênKhang  True

@TrầnNguyênKhang  Inner product on $E$ gives norm on $E$ and that norm gives metric on $E$ . By default we use that metric on inner product space. And convergence of sequence in $E$ means convergence with respect to that metric.

Yes, this definition is correct. If you want some intuition, the intutive meaning is that $||x-y||$ measures the distance between the vectors $x,y$. So convergence $x_n\to x$ can be defined very similarly to the definition of convergence of a sequence of real or complex numbers, just replace absolute value with that norm:
$\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists \ n_0\in\mathbb{N} \ \forall n\geq n_0: \ ||x_n-x||<\epsilon$
It's very easy to verify that this is equivalent to the condition $||x_n-x||\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So in most books, the latter is just taken as the definition of convergence.

Thanks everyone so much.
